# Is there a way to declutter Endogamy in DNA comparisons?

Tags: dna, endogamy

I've recently taken an Acestry DNA test to try and confirm my paternal line's great grandfather.  After getting the results, I thought I identified the correct one.  One of the nearest matched relatives and I share 168 cM's across 10 segments.  Matching trees, he looked to be a half 1st cousin 1x removed through my GGF (and 4th cousins 1x removed through another branch)

The catch: endogamy.  While the name and DNA lead me to think it was a valid match, the history was a little off. I then found a second potential GGF (from the same area with the same full name-first, middle and last - born within 10 years of the other).  The DNA matched cousin and I would be 4th cousins 1x removed **three** times over in this match (plus distant cousins in 2 or 3 more lines)

The community the shared relationships come from are the rather closed Mennonite/Amish communities of Eastern Lancaster County (Pennsylvania).

With the endogamy, I'm guessing DNA painter won't be of much help and I'd prefer not to shell out for the FT-DNA
Y test.  But beyond that, would I have any other options?